# How can I avoid divs from emptying themselves while scraping a dynamically generated website with Python/Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm making my best to express my problem because I'm a beginner, so I'm sorry if this question is already answered.
I'm trying to scrape data using Python Selenium from a webpage. That data is inside a lot of divs that they are generated when I scroll down. I've tried a lot of implementations but the problem is that when all the divs are generated, it only keeps content in just the ones that are in the scrolling field, in the other ones who are out of range, instead of data, i get blank output.

Is there a way to avoid content from divs to disappear, so when I scroll to the bottom, the content remains so I can scrape it.

Thanks!!

Comment: So, as you scroll down data erases which is available within a ```div``` ?. Why don't you try the approach like scroll down, save the data into the data structure, and repeat the procedure until you reach the bottom?

Comment: What do you mean blank output? Has the div have content in it, but for example the ```el.text``` from Selenium return empty? From the inspector do you see all divs after scrolling on only the ones in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in most cases try in the following order:

**elem.Text** if it doesn't work use **get_attribute('textContent')** if that too doesn't work use **getAttribute('value')**

getAttribute('value') works only if there is an attribute called 'value' in your element (like id, name etc)

So in most cases, if getText doesn't work use **.getAttribute('textContent')**
Use:

```
 i.get_attribute("textContent")
```

Because getText or text() actually uses innerText ,and will not detect text from hidden elements .

> Don't get confused by the differences between Node.textContent and
> HTMLElement.innerText. Although the names seem similar, there are
> important differences:
>
> textContent gets the content of all elements, including  and
> elements. In contrast, innerText only shows “human-readable” elements.
>
> textContent returns every element in the node. In contrast, innerText
> is aware of styling and won’t return the text of “hidden” elements.
>
> Moreover, since innerText takes CSS styles into account, reading the
> value of innerText triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date computed
> styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should be
> avoided when possible.)
>
> Unlike textContent, altering innerText in Internet Explorer (version
> 11 and below) removes child nodes from the element and permanently
> destroys all descendant text nodes. It is impossible to insert the
> nodes again into any other element or the same element after
> doing so

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent